# Tessnet using up all memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory, ocr

I'm trying to make a real time OCR application using Tessnet library. The idea is to store 5 images in a Bitmap array and perform OCR on them (every 2 seconds). The code runs okay, but it seems to take up a lot of memory. The application runs for like 30 minutes (when it uses up around 2GB memory) and then throws a Out of Memory exception. Any ideas to fix this? Thanks

This is my OCR function:

```
private void makeOCR()
{
   //Perform OCR in the image array

   x1 = string.Empty;

   //initialize OCR 
   Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
   ocr.Init(null, "eng", true);

   //loop through 5 bitmaps
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
     var result = ocr.DoOCR(imageArray[i], Rectangle.Empty);
     foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
     {
       x1 = x1 + word.Text;
     }
     x1 = x1 + Environment.NewLine;
   }

   ocr.Dispose();
   GC.Collect();

}
```

And, I'm trying to call this function on a timer tick event (every 2 seconds) on a new thread.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(makeOCR);
   t1.Start();
   textBox1.Text = x1;            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around the WEB I found there has been many reports of the memory leak while using Tessnet due to codes in Tessaract. There were instances where people loaded the Tessnet codes in a separate executable. I'm sharing my code which I used to do the same. (Now memory usage has been constant at 45 MB only for the main app)

First making a separate console application with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Runtime arguments:
    // [0] Folder Path
    // [1] N for numeral, A for all
    // [2] separator string
    // [3] echo (N for app closes silently, Y app waits for user input to close

    //Initialize
    string path = args[0];
    string num = args[1];
    string sep = args[2];
    string ech = args[3];
    string ocrval = String.Empty;
    bool numeral = false;

    if (num == "N")
      numeral = true;

    //Start TESSNET initialization
    Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
    ocr.Init(null, "eng", numeral);

    //Generate string array to read filenames in the path directory
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); 

    //Run OCR code
    foreach (string fn in allFiles)
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(fn);
        var result = ocr.DoOCR(bm, Rectangle.Empty);
        foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
        {
            ocrval = ocrval + word.Text;
        }
        ocrval = ocrval + sep;
        bm.Dispose();
    }

    //Write result to textfile
    File.WriteAllText(path+"/result/result.txt", ocrval);

    //echo output
    if (ech == "Y")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ocrval);
        Console.WriteLine("Process Completed. Press any key to close");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

So this application takes some basic parameters as the arguments. (To test code used the Properties > Debug > Command Line Arguments ). The folder path is the first argument which tells the application to look at which folder where all the images are stored. Then all the images are processed with Tessnet OCR and the results are written in a text file in **/path/result/result.txt** (the **/result** folder is to be created by the user)

Now in my main application where images are to be processed, the following code is placed.

First, the bitmaps need to saved in the same working directory (`workPath`) using
`Bitmap.Save` method.

Secondly, the console app is called by the main application with the following code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/temp/toe/Tessnet OCR Engine.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = workPath + " N && N";

// workPath is the directory where all images are stored
// N -> Numeral Only, A if all
// && -> Separator to define each the termination of every image's text
// N -> No Echo of results Y-> Show results on console and wait for user input.

process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

string res = File.ReadAllText(workPath.Text+"/result/result.txt");
string[] result;
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "&&" };
result = res.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Lastly the `result` string array holds the text of all the images in the `workPath` directory. The code would need some exception handling. The task of processing the images every 2-3 second is done by placing the second set of code in a timer tick event.